# Creating a 'const const' object in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, if I create a const array, I can still modify the object the variable points to:

```js
// The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. 
// It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const
const x = [1,2,3];
x.push(4);
console.log(x);
x=55 // But this is illegal and will error
console.log(x);
```

Is there a way to make the elements in an array immutable as well? Similar to something like `const int* const x;` in C?

Comment: `Object.freeze(x)` will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.freeze` to prevent an object (or array) from being changed:

```
const x = [1, 2, 3];
Object.freeze(x);

x.push(4); // This will throw an exception
```

Answer (score 1):

objects frozen with `Object.freeze()` are made immutable.

Here are the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Example:

```js
const x = [1,2,3];
Object.freeze(x);
```